# How to use MultiChoiceModeListener in ListVIew with and with out supports?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contextmenu, android-appcompat, action-menu

I am trying to add multi-select context menu to a `listview` with support library 22.1.1 using `AppCompatActivity` and `Toolbar`

Without support library
I can use `AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener`

with support library,
There is no equivalent `MultiChoiceModeListener` exists for support version that accept `android.support.v7.view.ActionMode` as parameter.

What should I do to get it working with support library?

Answer (score 0):

```
Start `ActionMode` in `Activity`:

   ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(new android.support.v7.view.ActionMode.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode mode) {

            }
        })
```

Use `MultiSelector` library:

https://github.com/bignerdranch/recyclerview-multiselect

http://ifeve.com/recyclerview-part-2%EF%BC%9A%E9%80%89%E6%8B%A9%E6%A8%A1%E5%BC%8F/